# How do I schedule emails using Quartz?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have a use case where I'll need to send emails around 100 users everyday in the evening. email content for each user maybe different? (I am using Quartz scheduler to do this)

This is more like a daily digest with different data for each user.

Currently, I am looping over the users list in the Job class itself and sending the mails one after the other.

How can I do this concurrently? like for example there could be 4 threads each of which would send emails to 25 distinct users.

Comment: How about you read user list like you are doing right now, But once you have read a user record and created email body for that user, you can start a new thread which shall take care of sending email. So this way, each record would be running concurrently while executing Email Sending Process

Comment: are you using spring-boot ?

Comment: @Deadpool No, I am using Spring 4.

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
class SendMail implements Runnable {

    private final List<User> users;

    public SendMail(List<User> users) {

        this.users = users;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // send mails to this.users list
    }
}

public static void main(String... f) throws InterruptedException {
    // users to send mails
    List<User> users = getUsers();
    // split list in 4 parts
    int split = users.size() / 4;
    // now you have splited the list in four
    List<User> split1 = users.subList(0, split);
    List<User> split2 = users.subList(split, 2 * split);
    List<User> split3 = users.subList(2 * split, 3 * split);
    List<User> split4 = users.subList(3 * split, users.size());
    // new thread for each part
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new SendMail(split1));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new SendMail(split2));
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new SendMail(split3));
    Thread t4 = new Thread(new SendMail(split4));
    // start sending mails
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    t4.start();
    // wait for all threads to send mails
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
    System.out.println("All mail sent!");
}
```